# Single datagrid multiple views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I would like to have a single datagrid bound to a large viewmodel. Then to give the user the ability to select via a combobox which set of properties in the viewmodel will be displayed in datagrid.

Clearly, I could have a datagrid for each layout and specify the column set for each datagrid. But, I feel like there should be a nicer way to do it?

For example, lets say my view model looks like:

```
public class MyGridRowViewModel{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string C {get;set;}
    public string D {get;set;}
}
```

And user can choose from combobox whether they want layout X or Y.

Layout X should show just `A` and `B` in the datagrid. Layout Y should show just `A` and `C` in the datagrid.

Comment: You can do this in the view, by capturing the combobox's selection changed event, and then manually showing/hiding the grid columns, but I can't think of a simple MVVM way of doing this offhand. You could do it, but I think the bindings and value converters would make it very complex scenario. The other way you suggested (multiple datagrids, and setting their visibility based on the combobox selection) is pretty straightforward, and can be done neatly in MVVM. We've used this technique, and it works fine.

Comment: You could bind the column visibility to the combobox and use a converter to show or hide it.

Comment: Use `ContentControl` with separate `ContentTemplate` .